# Android Listview : Center items in layout when fewer items

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that can have items from 1 to 100, dynamically varying.
However, when I have fewer items, I want the items to appear vertically centered in
the listview layout.  By default, Android draws the items form the top. I have attached a picture to illustrate what I need.

Is there any way I can achieve this, either by code or in XML layout ?

Thanks.

[image]

Edit: Based on the answers I have received now, I am adding more clarity to my question as the answers are off mark.

The positioning of the Listview in the main layout or positioning of individual item layouts is not an ISSUE here.  The listview is positioned properly as shown in the shaded background.  The question to which I need answer is:

1. Assume there are 10 items, the entire shared area of Listview will be used by items,
   possibly Items 1 to 5 are shown.
2. Assume there are 3 items only.  The listview is still shown but Items 1,2 and 3 are rendered at the top of the listview (shaded area).  However, in this case, I want the items to be drawn at centre of the listview's layout (as shown in the picture).

Anyway this can be done ?

Comment: Did you try "android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"....I think you might have already tried but still checking. And try with wrap_content for both width and height. This might work, please check.

Comment: share your `layout file`.

Comment: Try wrap your items inside linear layout that is set to wrap content and is centered inside single view of list view if thats what you want, otherwise im missing the point :P

Comment: @user3455363 if you keep up with your habit of not marking answers as answers, soon people will stop help you.

Comment: @Sufian : None of the answers worked for me.  Hence, have not marked them, not because I dont care.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to comment/respond to a proposed answer. Look around and you'll see many SO threads where questioner got his desired solution only after communicating with the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property

```
    mLoginUserNameValueView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

which one you want to center in the List view adapter and which position exactly where you need

e-x  you need your 55th position you want center the item means
     in getview you will use this line like below.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.navigationlayout,
                    null);
            mHolder.mLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.navigationLayout);
            mHolder.mNavigationtext = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.navigationText);
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        }
        if (\\Your desired position checking )
            \\ and set the above line here
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```